# Running apollo Server for Next.js app giving error

Tags: next.js, package.json, apollo-server

As I am using graphql and need to run local server (Apollo server), I am struggling to setup for the Next.js project. I am totally a beginner . In order to run the apollo server, it says to create server.ts , which I have created at the root of the project folder as below:
App - src
- server
- public

when I run 'npm start' , it gives error
pm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites

Is there anything I need to change in tscofig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `start` command in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file.

Ex:

```
"scripts": {
  "compile": "tsc",
  "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
},
```